# ORDER BY in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, sql-order-by

Currently in Tables i have Below Data

```
SORT    | QUESTION_SORT
---------------------------------------------------------- 
1   | 0
2   | 0
3   | 0
4   | 0
5   | 1
5   | 2
5   | 3     
6   | 1
6   | 2
6   | 3
7   | 1
7   | 2
7   | 3
8   | 1
8   | 2
9   | 0
10  | 0
```

I want Output formated like below based upon following criteria:

I want to **apply sorting on column `SORT` always**

1) if column `QUESTION_SORT` value is **`0`** then perform **only sorting**

2) if column `QUESTION_SORT` value is **non-zero** then perform **sorting with `GROUP BY`** of `QUESTION_SORT`

```
SORT    | QUESTION_SORT
---------------------------------------------------------- 
1   | 0
2   | 0
3   | 0
4   | 0
5   | 1
6   | 1
7   | 1
8   | 1
5   | 2
6   | 2
7   | 2
8   | 2
5   | 3     
6   | 3
7   | 3
9   | 0
10  | 0
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried solution suggested by Lamak but it is skipping the records which are having value 2 or 3 as `QUESTION_SORT`,

Query:

```
    Declare @TmpQuest table (Sort int , QUESTION_SORT int)
insert into @TmpQuest values (1   , 0)
insert into @TmpQuest values (2   , 0)
insert into @TmpQuest values (3   , 0)
insert into @TmpQuest values (4   , 0)
insert into @TmpQuest values (5   , 1)
insert into @TmpQuest values (5   , 2)
insert into @TmpQuest values (5   , 3)   
insert into @TmpQuest values (6   , 1)
insert into @TmpQuest values (6   , 2)
insert into @TmpQuest values (6   , 3)
insert into @TmpQuest values (7   , 1)
insert into @TmpQuest values (7   , 2)
insert into @TmpQuest values (7   , 3)
insert into @TmpQuest values (8   , 1)
insert into @TmpQuest values (8   , 2)
insert into @TmpQuest values (9   , 0)
insert into @TmpQuest values (10  , 0)

SELECT 
    [Sort], MIN(QUESTION_SORT) QUESTION_SORT 
FROM @TmpQuest 
GROUP BY [SORT]
```

Output:

```
Sort    QUESTION_SORT

1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   0
10  0
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Mihai That's not going to put the 9 and the 10 at the end.

Comment: What criteria do you have for the desired sort order?

Comment: it is the SORT 9 and 10 values that throw me - i would expect them to be listed after 4 | 0 and before 1 | 5

Comment: Anyway, you seem to want: `SELECT [SORT], MIN(QUESTION_SORT) QUESTION_SORT FROM YourTable GROUP BY [SORT]`

Comment: @Lamak: it will skip the records having 2 or 3 as value of `QUESTION_SORT`

Comment: @AdamWenger: I want to apply sorting on column `SORT` always with following criteria

1) if column `QUESTION_SORT` value is `0` then perform only sorting

2) if column `QUESTION_SORT` value is non-zero then perform sorting with `GROUP BY` of `QUESTION_SORT`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY CASE WHEN QUESTION_SORT = 0 THEN SORT ELSE QUESTION_SORT END, SORT`

Comment: @Lamak: thanks for your support but I'm still not able get desired output. please checkout [this sqlfiddle query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#%212/ef635f/2) as per your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some how i manage to solve my query as per my Required Output, also change query in Sql Fiddle to get desired output: [Sql fiddle query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef635f/53)

**Query :**

```
SELECT sort, 
       question_sort, 
       (SELECT Min(TMP1.sort) + ( tmpquest.question_sort * 0.005 ) 
        FROM   tmpquest TMP1 
        WHERE  Tmp1.question_sort = tmpquest.question_sort 
        GROUP  BY TMP1.question_sort) AS MinValByGrp 
FROM   tmpquest 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN question_sort = 0 THEN sort 
            ELSE minvalbygrp 
          END, 
          sort
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
SORT    QUESTION_SORT   
1         0 
2         0 
3         0 
4         0         
6         1 
7         1 
8         1 
5         2 
6         2 
7         2 
8         2 
5         3 
6         3 
7         3 
9         0 
10        0
```